# error: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file

Tags: php, laravel, file

I have a sample code using laravel

> error: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file

```
$test = 'sample_remote_tempfile.txt';
$content = Storage::get('upload/'.$test);
foreach (file($content) as $line) {
     explode(" , ", trim($content),"\n");
     die($content);
}
```

Comment: `$content = Storage::get('upload/'.$test);` has no directory found. why not include `base_url()`?

Comment: or $content = public_path(''upload').'/'.$test; actually it depends upon how you've defined your filesystem.

Comment: @Roshan thanks for the answer what do you mean base_url()? sorry im new at php i tried Storage::url('upload/'.$test);

Comment: @ViperTecPro thanks for the answer i will try public_path

Answer (score 0):

(   IF USE LARAVEL   )

use command, to clear autoload files, and update routes to load new names of clases.

```
> composer dumpautoload
```

Check your routes file, to verify that all class names are spelled correctly

```
routes\web.php
```